# Is there a way to replace library classes?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Lets say that a lot of functionality are using methods from this class `test.MyClass`, but it's very slow and I'd like to code in JNI in hopes of improving the timing...

Is there a way to replace `test.MyClass` so that the library does not need to be changed, but the codes in the library will use the new `test.MyClass` with native implementations for certain methods from now on? It's the classic "PC is fine but the timing for Android is crap" problem.

Comment: JNI does not improve timing in most cases. It may even make it worse since calling native methods has some overhead. Are you sure it's not the classic "My algorithm is bad but it's not visible on PC because they have more processing power" problem?

Answer (score -1):

Just create your `test.MyClass` in the same package/hierarchical structure as the one in the package you want to override. The `classloader` should load your implementation first and if it tries to load the one from other library the load will fail, because there can be only one loaded instance in the classpath.

Comment: It's not always that simple. The VM considers the pair {package_name, classloader} when determining whether two classes are in the same package. Different class loaders means the VM sees them as independent classes that happen to have the same name, so both will be loaded. If you try to replace java.lang.String, you'll end up with two distinct String classes that don't interact with each other, which is a problem when you try to pass an "app string" to something in the core classes or vice-versa. (There are some funky edge cases... I don't recommend doing this.)

Comment: Example: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2-release/tests/068-classloader/